# How do you find a coefficient experimentally and graphically?

Tags: numerical-methods

If I did not know that the coefficient $K$ of the frequency of the pendulum; $\frac{1}{t} = K*(g/L)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, how would I go about finding it? Is there any textbook that I could take a look at? I found some equations through unconventional means with similar structures, but my numbers do not agree with the answers on textbooks. I just need some idea.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a graph of $\dfrac{1}{t}$ on the $y$-axis and $\sqrt{\dfrac{g}{L}}$ on the $x$-axis.

If the points lie on a straight line passing through the origin, then your experimental value for $K$ is the gradient of the line.

Alternatively draw a graph of $t$ on the $y$-axis and $\sqrt{\dfrac{L}{g}}$ on the $x$-axis to get an estimate of $\dfrac{1}{K}$.

The value of $\dfrac{1}{2 \pi}$ comes from solving the equation associated with [simple harmonic motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion#Mass_on_a_simple_pendulum), which is an approximation to a mass on a simple pendulum with small angles of deflection.